# Filtering entity by collection of IDs LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need to filter entity with LINQ by collection of IDs. What I am trying to do better explains following sql query:

```
 select * from Person where PersonID in (1,2,3)
```

I have List collection which contain collection of IDs and need to retrieve all persons with same ID like in collection.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myList.Where(item => ids.Contains(item)).ToList()
```